# rendering default application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It appears that Rails won't render my default application layout, so I have to specify it every time I do a call from a controller.

```
render :layout => 'application'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: try writing layout 'application' in your ApplicationController